# PHP script doesn't work with // comments

Tags: php, comments

I have a PHP script that doesn't seem to work when it contains a // type comment. I mean, the script just doesn't seem to execute beyond the // style comment. E.g.

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain');

// some comment
echo "OK";
```

doesn't work, no output. but:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain');

echo "OK";
```

does work. I see OK as output. And:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain');

/* some comment */    
echo "OK";
```

Also works. Again I see OK as output.

I never encountered this before. Could there be any PHP settings that control this behavior? How do I make my // style comments work?

Comment: I think you missed a ; after the echo statement

Comment: What does the actual code look like?

Comment: @Josiah: I forgot to type the ;. they are in the code.

Comment: @Gumbo: This IS the actual code. I didn't copy and paste because typing it in was just as fast (although I forgot to type the ;).

Comment: Your first example (the buggy one) works on Win XP with PHP 5.3.0 under Apache and LightTPD, the fault might be your editor I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of platform are you on and which editor are you using? Because the only thing I can think of is that the interpreter doesn't like your newlines. Are you using Apple style (`\r` only) newlines?

I'm not able to reproduce your problem on PHP 5.2.9-4 running on Linux, not with Mac encoding either.

Just to be sure, have you tried adding a closing tag after the echo statement? (`?>`). Otherwise, add that now and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Possibly, UNIX newlines on a Windows system may also cause a problem (if the Windows interpreter needs to see \r\n and it only get \n).

Comment: The closing tag is optional (see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Comment: @Gumbo: Oh, didn't use to be though, as far as I know... goes to show how long it's been since I've done serious PHP work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and adding a closing tag (?>) fixed it for me.

```
<header>
<?php // require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/common/header.php'; ?>
</header>
```